# Shmona Vearbaim Veshalosh Meot Mi Yodea?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred forty eight?

### שמונה וארבעים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Numbers). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 348? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 348, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

NO GEMATRIAS!

Comment: Formatted to parallel previous posts in the series. Also, no lazy gematria tell-off? :)

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120757/tisha-va-arbaim-ushlosh-meyot-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 8):

348 are the negative commandments as enumerated in the Introduction to [Halachot Gedolot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halachot_Gedolot):

> אילו מאתים ושבעים ושבעה לאוין ושבעים ואחת עבירות שבמיתות ששה ענשים הרי אלו שלש מאות וארבעים ושמונה מצות לא תעשה
>
> These are the 277 prohibitions, plus the 71 sins that [incur] the six punishments; behold these are the 348 negative commandments.

Answer (score 4):

348 are the days of the year one is permitted to eat in a kesidran non-leap year (354 minus the 6 fast days (the five derabban and Yom Kippur) equals 348.

Comment: Do you realize that most years don't have 354 days?

Comment: This doesn’t account for תענית בכורות. Perhaps this should be emended to read “on which a non-firstborn is permitted to eat.”

Comment: @DonielF As a bechor myself, I always make a siyum. If you find me even one bechor who fasts, I'll emend the answer.

Comment: @TheAsh Making a siyum is a "cheat" which many bechoros do (while I'm not a bechor, the bechoros in my family partake in such a siyum). The base halacha is that a bechor must fast on Erev Pesach; a siyum is merely a way out of it.

Comment: @DonielF No, it's not a cheat. It works only because it's not a real fast - it's merely a minhag.

Comment: @TheAsh SA OC 470:1: הבכורות מתענין בערב פסח בין בכור מאב בין בכור מאם ויש מי שאומר נקבה בכורה מתענה. No mention of minhag or siyum. The earliest I could find was the Mishnah Berurah 470:10, who says just the opposite of your preposition: not that the fast is minhag, therefore we break it for a Seudas Mitzvah, but whether a firstborn can break for a Seudas Mitzvah is minhag - some places are stringent, some places are lenient.

Answer (score 3):

348 are the days where it is permitted to own Chametz in Israel (including partial days). (In a shaleim non-leap year.)