# Chamishim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred fifty?

### חמישים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 350? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 350, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Skip lazy gematria answers; give us something to sink our teeth into.

Comment: Previous: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120757/tisha-va-arbaim-ushlosh-meyot-mi-yodeya

Comment: Next: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120826/echad-vachamishim-ushlosh-meyot-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bereishis 9:28](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.9.28?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0):

> וַֽיְחִי־נֹ֖חַ אַחַ֣ר הַמַּבּ֑וּל שְׁלֹ֤שׁ מֵאוֹת֙ שָׁנָ֔ה וַֽחֲמִשִּׁ֖ים שָׁנָֽה׃
>
> Noah lived after the Flood 350 years.

Answer (score 4):

[According to Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Genesis.15.13.1?vhe=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann,_1929-1934&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)<sup>1</sup>, the lives of Kehat (133), Amram (137) and Moshe (80) at the Exodus added together equal 350, which is inconsistent with the 400 years of the sojourn in Egypt.

---

<sup>1</sup> The English translation used by Sefaria made a mistake in the calculations: [Kehat lived 133](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.6.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0), not 130, and for this they had to write "*about* 350".

Answer (score 3):

When Moshe took כֶּ֣סֶף הַפִּדְי֑וֹם (redemption money) as mentioned in [Bamidbar 3:50](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.3.50?lang=bi&aliyot=0), the Torah writes:

> מֵאֵ֗ת בְּכ֛וֹר בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל לָקַ֣ח אֶת־הַכָּ֑סֶף חֲמִשָּׁ֨ה וְשִׁשִּׁ֜ים וּשְׁלֹ֥שׁ מֵא֛וֹת וָאֶ֖לֶף בְּשֶׁ֥קֶל הַקֹּֽדֶשׁ׃
>
> He took the money from the first-born of the Israelites, 1,365 sanctuary shekels.

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.3.50?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.3.50.1&lang2=bi) there provides a breakdown of how the total came to be, and mentions that 350 shekalim would come from 70 firstborn:

> חמשה וששים ושלש מאות ואלף A THOUSAND THREE HUNDRED AND THREESCORE AND FIVE — This is the total sum: five shekels per head for two hundred firstborn if one thousand shekels; **for seventy firstborn is three hundred and fifty shekels**, and three firstborn give fifteen shekels, — thus altogether 1,365. — He, (Moses) said, “How shall I proceed? Any firstborn to whom I will say, “Give five shekels’ will answer me, ‘I am one of those redeemed by the Levites’!” What, then, did he do? He brought 22,000 tablets and inscribed them with the words “A son of Levi”, and 273 tablets, and wrote upon them the words “Five shekels”. These he mixed up, putting them into an urn. He said to them, “Come and draw your tablets and decide the matter by lot” (Sanhedrin 17a).