# Echad Vachamishim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred fifty-one?

### אחד וחמישים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 351? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 351, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Lazy gematria answers here may be too much for a person to bear.

Comment: Previous: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120796/chamishim-ushlosh-meyot-mi-yodeya

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120468/discussion-on-question-by-isaac-moses-echad-vachamishim-ushlosh-meyot-mi-yodey).

Comment: When you say "lazy gematria", do you mean all gematria?

Comment: @Harel13 By "lazy gematria," I mean just trivially translating the number into letters, e.g. "355 is the gematria of שנה." There are definitely specific gemtarias that are significant, as such, in Judaism, such as [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85998/2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest Jewish year is 353 days. Thus in a year that has 353 days, there is 351 days between the end of Rosh HaShana to the next Rosh HaShana.